# Get filtered items from a CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, collectionview

I have a `ListCollectionView` which has had a filter applied to it.  In order to get the filtered items from the list (e.g. to write to a file), is there a clean way of doing it.

My current solution is

```
var filteredItems = originalCollection.Where(i => view.Filter(i));
```

In the code I do check for nulls on `originalCollection` and `view.Filter`.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: `var filteredItems = originalCollection.FindAll(view.Filter);` also works

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `GetEnumerator` method takes the filter into account, so you can just `foreach` over the view:

```
ICollectionView view = ...
view.Filter = ...

foreach(Foo o in view)
{
    ...
}
```

(assuming the objects in the original collection are of type `Foo`).

You can also use the `Cast` extension method:

```
var filteredItems = view.Cast<Foo>();
```

Comment: ICollectionView view = ...

Please show a full example. 
I have filtered items in a DataGrid and the view i get from GetDefualtView 

How do i get the "CurrentView" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example how to get filtrated items from DataGrid:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(*yourDataGrid*);
foreach(Foo o in view)
{
  ...
}
```